# Improve signal quality with ddwrt using Buffalo Nfiniti router

Tags: router, dd-wrt

I have a Buffalo Nfiniti router, and I am running dd-wrt.

My signal quality is at 40%, on my mac it is fine but a hp computer in another room has internet issues (the connection comes and goes etc.)

What options do I have with this setup to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://compnetworking.about.com/od/wirelessfaqs/f/extendwifirange.htm) is a decent article that goes over several options, such as a repeater, signal booster, second access point, replacement antenna, etc.